# Magento2 slick slider issue on page load

Tags: magento2, requirejs, magento2.2.3, slick

I am applying slick slider on the home page at widget but on page load, it is not loading properly but after page load, ends it works fine

[image]

and when the page loads completely it looks like this 
[image]

here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    require(['jquery', 'slick'], function($){ 
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

           jQuery('#blog-post-silder').not('.slick- 
   initialized').slick({
      dots: false,
      infinite: false,
      speed: 300,
      slidesToShow: 3.1,
      settings: "unslick",
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 1024,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 3.1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            infinite: false,
            dots: false
          }
        },
         {
          breakpoint:767,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 3.2,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
             dots: false
          }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 600,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 3.1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
             dots: false
          }
        },
           {
          breakpoint: 320,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 2.1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
             dots: false
          }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 480,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 2.1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
             dots: false
          }
        }
        // You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
        // settings: "unslick"
        // instead of a settings object
      ]
       });
       });
       });
    </script>
      <ol id="blog-post-silder" class="product-items <?= /* @noEscape 
    */ $type ?>"  >
```

thanks a lot

Comment: is there any inline or internal css ??

Comment: i have added slick slider css

Comment: @AshishRamchandani: found any solution for this issue, please let us know

Comment: This same issue effected on Magento 2.4.3 p1 version, If anyone know findout solution